# WP7: Questions regarding Touch Gestures

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone 7 (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). What I would like to do is check for a flick on a text block. On a flick up I want to increment a value and on a flick down I want to decrement the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<TextBlock Text="0">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick" />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</TextBlock>
```

```cs
private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
{
    //use e.Direction to determine which way
}
```