# Get events of Gestures in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using a pivot page in my wp7 application. The PivotItems are added programatically. I need to get events of all the gestures. How can I get them?

And, how to know the direction of flick gesture? After swiping how to get details of the current item.

I was trying this :  [WP7: Questions regarding Touch Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684073/wp7-questions-regarding-touch-gestures). But could not add

```
<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick" />
</toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

when I am trying to add this, an error occurs.

How can I get gesture events?

Comment: What error do you get. Please post it.

Comment: Error 1 'toolkit' is an undeclared prefix. 
Error 2 The attachable property 'GestureListener' was not found in type 'GestureService'.
Error 3 The type 'toolkit:GestureListener' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: that error is fixed. These two are the most important questions which I am expecting a sudden reply. how to know the direction of flick gesture? After swiping how to get details of the current item. ------ Please help me

Comment: Well then, Whether you're missing any assembly reference or any references remains unbuilt?

Comment: The direction of the flick gesture, as determined by the flick velocities. `public Orientation Direction {get { return Math.Abs(_velocity.X) >= Math.Abs(_velocity.Y) ? Orientation.Horizontal : Orientation.Vertical; } }` Its totally depends on the velocity, you can use simple conditional operation to determine its direction .

Comment: @nelson-t-joseph, please be advised that the GestureListener is considered deprecated in the Silverlight Windows Phone Toolkit - Nov 2011 (please check [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is additional support for detecting touch in the XNA library. Trying adding the  Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch reference to your project

Include the following using statement:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
```

Subscribe to the required events in your constructor as follows:

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap | GestureType.Flick;
```

On your control create an event for Manipulation Completed as follows:

```
ManipulationCompleted="Object_ManipulationCompleted"
```

You could add code to the that event method to track the type of events that have been completed with the following code:

```
private void Object_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

        if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Tap)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Flick)
        {
            //The delta contains the direction of the flick (negative/positive)
            //gesture.Delta.Y;
            //gesture.Delta.X;
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: //The delta contains the direction of the flick (negative/positive) . Is there any way to check its Towards top direction or towards bottom direction or towards Left side or Rightside ?