# Page animation with visual feedback on drag gesture

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, gestures

I was wondering, I'm currently using a slide in and out page transition when the user presses a Next of Previous button on the appbar.
( concept: going through a set of articles inside a selected category )

This all looks great, I'm also able add the drag / flick gesture listeners to trigger this page transition... so no problems there.

But now I wanted to add the final part, when the user starts the drag / flick gesture, show this visually so that the page follows the gesture and 'slides' out of frame.

But how to do this? An example would be great :)
But there is also a small extra thing, I don't want the user to always do a full drag... so if we are over 2/3 of the screen, auto start the page transition IF the gesture stops ( so the user lifts up his finger )

So I would like to create a nice reading experience that shows the gesture visualy and performs the page transition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first started with the [DragFlickBehavior](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.be/2011/03/simple-windows-phone-7-silverlight.html) from @LocalJoost and it actually worked great!
But in the end I switched to a headerless pivot! Works also great!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9915016/1565574

In the ManipulationCompleted you'll be able to detect the GestureType and take an action there.

And I found that link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342558/1565574 (using the GestureService)

Comment: Hmm I already do this... the part missing is the 'visual' part, in other words move the complete page while doing the gesture.

Comment: Then you can check that: http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2012/08/how-to-create-swiping-gesture-list-items-for-windows-phone-7/ The swipe gesture is for a ListBoxItem but I'm sure you can use something like that for the entire page